# Can you use selected="selected" to auto select selectize.js on load?

Tags: html, selectize.js

I'm working on a project where every select field is expected to use selectize.js. There can be any number of select fields on the page and I never know so it has to be abstract.

The init is very simple:

```
$('.selectize').selectize({
    create: true
});
```

You'd think the default selected value of any given select would be used when selectize inits...

```
<select class="selectize">
    <option value="1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="2">Option 2</option>
    <option value="3" selected="selected">Option 3</option>
</select>
```

But for some reason selectize only sets the first option as selected when init runs.

Am I missing something in the docs? Or does selectize really not use the selected attribute from html?

This also doesn't work when using `<option value="3" selected>`

To clarify, this is a data filtering utility where clicking directional filters, select boxes, etc are expected to reload the page while maintaining all selections. Thus, I have to rely on PHP GET params to set the selected items. That part is working as expected and I have verified that by disabling selectize.

**EDIT**
as requested, this is all standard implementation. Selectize works fine, no console errors. It just inits with only the first value selected.

**UPDATE**

As answered below, you can use selected but for reasons unknown I can't in my setup. Must be a conflict somewhere. Anyhow, if anyone else has this issue, this is how I resolved mine. On my init, I loop through each select that has a matching get param and set it by comparing against the get value. The sample is here, which is not complete code but enough to get someone running...

```
var ss = $('#some-select').selectize();
var selectize = ss[0].selectize;
selectize.setValue(selectize.search(get_value).items[0].id);
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and clarify: How and when are you executing that script? Is the DOM loaded when you do this? How have you included all the necessary libraries and plug-ins? It seems to work, if I copy-paste the HTML into the [Selectize demo page](https://selectize.github.io/selectize.js/) and run the jQuery code in the console.

Comment: @Xufox - jquery document.ready. all is included as expected and selectize works fine in all other respects. It just doesn't utilize my selected values

Comment: Doesn't answer the question of whether or not setting the `selected` attribute should work or not, but you can pass an array of `items` that you want selected by default as one of your init parameters to skin this cat another way - see [`items` under general settings on this page of the docs](https://github.com/selectize/selectize.js/blob/master/docs/usage.md).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can use `selected` with selectize for your default `option`. Must be a conflict with some other code not included in your question because it looks like selectize handles the `selected` attribute as you would expect. See working snippet below.

```js
$('.selectize').selectize({
  create: true
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Selectize</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/selectize.js/0.12.6/css/selectize.default.min.css">
</head>

<body>

  <select class="selectize">
    <option value="1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="2">Option 2</option>
    <option value="3" selected>Option 3</option>
  </select>
  
  <select class="selectize">
    <option value="1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="2" selected>Option 2</option>
    <option value="3">Option 3</option>
  </select>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/selectize.js/0.12.6/js/standalone/selectize.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Certainly has to be although there's not a great deal else in my code. I did find a way to get through it but your answer basically answers the actual question definitively.